# Open a .BAT file in another directory from within a .BAT file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a .BAT file on my desktop that calls another .BAT file in the same location named MySQL:

```
start MySQL
```

pretty complicated right? How could I access this same file if it was in c:\ProgramFiles? I know I need to first go up one directory, but I cannot for the life of me make it work. I'm using windows 10 by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do like this example :

```
@echo off
CD /D "%Programfiles%\Mozilla FireFox\" 
Start "" Firefox.exe
```

and in your case it should be like this :

```
@echo off
CD /D "%Programfiles%\Sqlfolder\" 
Start "" Mysql.exe
```